# PHP pagination loop issue

Tags: php, pagination

I tried to make a PHP pagination like this:

```
$count = $this->dataBaseFunctions->countItems();
$resultperPage = 10;
$offset = 0;    
$adjacents = 3;
$totalPages = ceil(intval($count) / $resultperPage);


if (isset($_GET['offset'])) {
  $offset = trim($_GET['offset']);
}

 $j = $adjacents;
while ($j > 0) {
  if (($offset / 10) - 1 > 0) {
    echo '<a href="anypage/' . ($offset - 10 - ($j * 10)) . '" class="pagelink">' . ($offset - 10 - ($j * 10)) . '</a> ';        
  }
  $j--;
}

/*for ($j = $adjacents; $j > 0; $j--) {
  echo '<a href="anypage/' . ($offset - 10 - ($j * 10)) . '" class="pagelink">' . ($offset - 10 - ($j * 10)) . '</a> ';
}*/

echo '<a href="anypage/' . ($offset - 10) . '" class="pagelink current">[' . ($offset - 10) . '] </a> ';

for ($j = 1; $j < ($adjacents + 1); $j++) {
  echo '<a href="anypage/' . ($offset - 10 + ($j * 10)) . '" class="pagelink">' . ($offset - 10 + ($j * 10)) . '</a> ';
}
```

The result should look like this (Brackets = current clicket page):
[0] 1 2 3

When I click "3" it should look like this (works so far):
0 1 2 [3] 4 5 6

But when I click "1" the result looks like this:
-2 -1 0 [1] 2 3 4

The "0" is not a problem, I just 'echoed' it for debugging.
I know that I dont set the right conditions for not showing pages below 1 but I dont get it how to make it right. Seems like I have tomatoes on my eyes... The echo is just for testing - later I save the whole pagination links into a variable to assign it to the bottom of the page. Its a bit of debugging code you see here but it shows what I try to do. Please let me know if I can improve the question or if there are missing informations like: "why you do ($offset / 10) -1 > 0" ;-)

Later I need to do same stuff in JS but I think I can manage that, when I know what I did wrong in the PHP version.

*Maybe it's a bad Idea what I try to do there?

Comment: What is `$adjacents` good for?

Comment: $adjacents is the count to the left and to the right of the current page. So if i click for example "5", the left side shows 2 3 4 and the right side 6 7 8 like 2 3 4 [5] 6 7 8. 1 and 9 are not shown. $adjacents = 3, shows a range of 7 pages at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should do the trick:

> Now including the $adjacents

```
$count = $this->dataBaseFunctions->countItems();
$resultperPage = 10;
$offset = 0;
$adjacents = 3;
$totalPages = ceil(intval($count) / $resultperPage);

if (isset($_GET['offset'])) {
   $offset = trim($_GET['offset']);
}      
$start = ($offset-$adjacents) > 0 ? ($offset-$adjacents) : 0;
$end = ($offset+$adjacents) < $totalPages ? ($offset+$adjacents) : $totalPages;

$pager = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalPages; $i++) {
    if ($i >= $start && $i <= $end) {
        $pager .= $offset != $i ? '<a href="anypage/' . $i . '" class="pagelink">' . $i . '</a> ' : "[$i] "; 
    }
}
echo $pager;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it! What about $adjacents?

Comment: Your code looks like it shows all pages at once, but i only want to show 7 pages at once.

Comment: I updated my answer with the $adjacents - does it work for you now like this?

Comment: This code works fine! Thanks a lot for your help, I like the short solution!

I modified it a little bit so it fits with my example - here it is:
`$start = (($offset / 10) - $adjacents) > 0 ? (($offset / 10) - $adjacents) : 0;
    $end = (($offset / 10) + $adjacents) < $totalPages ? (($offset / 10) + $adjacents) : $totalPages;

    $pager = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $totalPages; $i++) {
      if ($i >= $start && $i <= $end) {
        $pager .= ($offset / 10) -1 != $i ? '<a href="anypage/' . ($i * 10) . '" class="pagelink">' . $i  . '</a> ' : "[$i] ";
      }
    }`

*not formatted in comments